# How stable are clocks in network equipment

Tags: switch, router, ntp

Most high end network equipment (switches and routers) can act as a NTP-server for hosts in the network, but I cant find any information on how stable these are. Does anyone have any information or insight?

Edit: So, my actual question is: Are switches and routers usable as ntp servers in a network? Or should we go for specific hardware?

Comment: Kinda depends on what what you mean by stable.  My monitoring of my HP switch seems to show that it stays within +/- 0.002 second relative to my monitoring server.  Is that stable enough?  Like almost everything, define your requirements, then test&monitor.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have no clue about the internal clock stability, but it doesn't matter much since you absolutely want those devices to be be synchronized, i.e. be NTP clients of a trusted source.

This is the only way to ensure that logs (or snmp traps or whatever monitoring you use) are consistent among the devices, to allow a good interpretation.

Of course there should be no significant deviation between two NTP update. I have no real data about this but I never saw this problem arise with properly configured devices.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the stratum level concept, and the use of multiple time servers, too.

Comment: Yes, of course they are synchronized. But the question is, are they themselves good sources of time for the rest of the network.

Comment: @Peter, They will pass on the time they get, and they should be synchronizing with a good source. You need to understand stratum levels. As you go down the stratum, you get lees accurate. What level of accuracy do you need? You will be accurate withing a very small fraction of a second.

Comment: @RonMaupin, I think we are on different pages here. I know how NTP works with stratum levels and so on. What I want to know is how stable time source a L3 switch from let say cisco/dell/hp is compared to a dedicated hardware like https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/products/rack-mount-1u-ntp-server.htm synced with GPS and equipped with a high precision crystal.

Comment: My question stands, "_What level of accuracy do you need? You will be accurate withing a very small fraction of a second._"

Answer (score 2):

Clocks of network devices usually DO NOT have high-quality oscillators. Because those oscillators are expensive hardware.

If all you need is to distribute wall clock time through NTP (with millisecond precision) , they might suffice.

If you need high accuracy for services like TDM over packet, you will likely need either SyncE or PTP (precision time protocol), for sub-microsecond precision, and clock sources with high-accuracy oscillator (as you said, specific hardware).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on the level of accuracy which you need. For network logs and PCs/servers running normal applications, it is more than accurate enough. Very precise applications may require a dedicated GPS clock in the device.

The `show ntp status` command on Cisco devices gives you a lot of information.

```
Clock is synchronized, stratum 3, reference is 149.125.221.49 
nominal freq is 250.0000 Hz, actual freq is 249.9981 Hz, precision is 2**21
ntp uptime is 6979200 (1/100 of seconds), resolution is 4016
reference time is DA773F8B.E3CD5B84 (14:28:59.889 CST Tue Feb 23 2016)
clock offset is -0.3724 msec, root delay is 18.04 msec
root dispersion is 7.97 msec, peer dispersion is 0.14 msec
loopfilter state is 'CTRL' (Normal Controlled Loop), drift is 0.000007535 s/s
system poll interval is 1024, last update was 248 sec ago.
```